# Bizarre behavior of scipy.linalg.eigvalsh in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I wanted to compare `scipy`'s and `numpy`'s routine for calculating eigenvalues of Hermitian matrices (`eigvalsh`), and ran into some unexpected behavior.

In particular, `scipy`'s `eigvalsh` routine returns practically the same eigenvalues as `numpy`'s `eigvalsh` routine, but only for matrices with dimension smaller than 2000 x 2000. Example from Spyder 2.3.7 (Python 3.5):

```
In [1]: import scipy
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: H = np.random.rand(1999,1999) + np.random.rand(1999,1999) * 1j
   ...: H = H + H.conj().T
   ...: Es = scipy.linalg.eigvalsh(H)
   ...: En = np.linalg.eigvalsh(H)
   ...: sum(abs(En - Es))
Out[3]: 1.85734656821257e-10

In [4]: H = np.random.rand(2000,2000) + np.random.rand(2000,2000) * 1j
   ...: H = H + H.conj().T
   ...: Es = scipy.linalg.eigvalsh(H)
   ...: En = np.linalg.eigvalsh(H)
   ...: sum(abs(En - Es))
Out[4]: 89786.239714130075
```

In fact, if `H.shape >= (2000,2000)`, the array of eigenvalues `Es` contains only zeros, apart from the last element, which equals 24 times the length of the array:

```
In [5]: np.unique(Es[:-1])
Out[5]: array([ 0.])

In [6]: Es[-1]
Out[6]: 48000.0
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Which version of numpy and scipy are you using? (Check `np.__version__`, `scipy.__version__`.)

Comment: numpy 1.10.1 and scipy 0.16.0.

Comment: Also, what platform?  What OS, and is python 32- or 64-bit?  FWIW, your example works fine for me (numpy 1.10.1, scipy 0.16.0, python 2.7.11 (64 bit), Mac OS X 10.9.5).

Comment: It also works for me with python 3.5.1.

Comment: My OS is Windows 10, Python is 64 bit.

Comment: Spyder is from the Anaconda distribution I downloaded from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

Comment: You might want to report the issue at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues.  Also, see if you get the strange behavior reported in https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/507

Comment: How reproducible is it (I cannot reproduce it with as well)? If your matrix is conditioned poorly, then it is probable that you'll get significantly deviating results when using different algorithms. ``np.linalg.cond()`` can give you a pointer in that direction. Also adding ``np.eye(2000)`` to your matrix ensures better numeric properties.

Comment: The behavior is reproducable in a sense that it manifests every time I open Spyder, even for sparse, well-conditioned matrices.

Answer (score 0):

For `*.linalg.eigvalsh` routines, `numpy` invokes LAPACK `-EVD` routines, which are based on a divide-and-conquer algorithm. `scipy` invokes LAPACK `-EVR`, which uses a different algorithm.

For LAPACK docs, [see here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node30.html). This explains the slight numerical differences you're seeing in the under-2000 case.

The "all zeros" situation does indeed look like a bug, but I cannot replicate on `scipy == '0.17.1'` and `np == '1.11.0'`. Does the issue persist after upgrading?